# If a group endomorphism restricts to a permutation on a generating set, is the endomorphism injective?

Tags: group-theory

Let $S$ be a generating set for a group $G$. If $\phi: G \to G$ is an endomorphism such that $\phi(S)=S$ and $\phi\restriction_S: S \to S$ is a bijection, can we conclude that $\phi$ is injective?

Comment: Hagen von Eitzen has shown that the answer is no in general. But I am not sure whether this is possible if $S$ is a finite generating set. There do exist examples of finitely generated nonHopfian groups i.e. groups with surjective but not injective endomorphisms, but I have never come across an example in which the endomorphisms permute a finite generating set, and it might not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $k\in \Bbb Z$ let $A_k=\Bbb Z/42\Bbb Z$ with  $k> 0$ and $A_k=\Bbb Z$ if $k\le 0$. Now let $$G=\bigoplus_{k\in\Bbb Z}A_k  $$
with generating set $S$ obtained by taking the standard generator per summand, i.e., $S=\{\,s_n\mid n\in\Bbb Z\,\}$ where 
$$s_n(k)=\begin{cases}1\,(+42\Bbb Z)&\text{if }k=n\\0\,(+42\Bbb Z)&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Consider the endomorphism $\phi\colon G\to G$ that is induced by being the identity map $A_k\to A_{k+1}$ for $k\ne0$, and the canonical pojection $A_0\to A_1$. Then $\phi\restriction_S$ is a bijection $S\to S$ (namely $s_n\mapsto s_{n+1}$), but $\phi$ is not injective.